# Bb10 connecting qml layouts

Tags: qml, blackberry-10

How do i load a view when i click a button from one qml layout to other qml? as I'm having a login button if i click the button i want to display the next screen, which is the landing screen, how to do this? can anyone send some idea? Thanks. I know the onclicked but how do i reference it to other qml layouts?

```
ImageButton {
                    id: btnlogin
                    topMargin: 50
                    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/button_login.png"

                    onClicked: {
                        onClicked: {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.
You can :

1 - Call a C++ function that will show the next screen. To do that you have to create a Q_INVOKABLE method (for instance in the Class associated with your current Page) such as

```
Q_INVOKABLE void showLoginPage();
```

Then you call it from the QML this way

```
onClicked: {
    controller.showLoginPage();
}
```

2 - Show the next screen directly from the QML.

```
onClicked: {
    // Directly show the next page from here
}
```

Then to actually show the next screen, there also are different ways depending on the kind of navigation you have :

1 - Push the screen if you are using a NavigationPane :

C++ example

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("LoginPage.qml");

// Creates the root using the page node 
Page *loginPage = qml->createRootNode<Page>();

// Push the login page
navigationPane->push(loginPage);
```

QML example

```
ImageButton {
    id: btnlogin
    topMargin: 50
    verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
    horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
    defaultImageSource: "asset:///images/button_login.png"
    onClicked: {
         // show login page when the button is clicked
         var page = getLoginPage();
         navigationPane.push(page);
    }
    property Page loginPage
    function getLoginPage() {
        if (!loginPage) {
            loginPage = loginPageDefinition.createObject();
        }
        return loginPage;
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: loginPageDefinition
            source: "LoginPage.qml"
        }
    ]
```

2 - You could also use Sheets

3 - ...

There are many ways to achieve what you want to do.

Hope those little tips will help.

Comment: Do I have to delete the onSystemLanguageChanged on both cpp and hpp? I can't seem to run the app. It's not on the navpane, I have my own button for login :)

Comment: What are you trying to do at the end ? Creating the new page directly from QML or by going back to C++ ? What's the error you get ? onSystemLanguageChanged shouldn't be an issue there...

Comment: When I use the navigationpane, What else do i have to include?

Comment: The navigationPane allows you to stack Pages. This is a "navigation structure". http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__navigationpane.html. I was simply showing a way for you to show your next Page in the case you were already using a NavigationPane to stack your first Page. The link I give you shows you how to use NavigationPane in C++ and QML